# Install QGIS 1.9 on Fedora 19

Tags: qgis, fedora

I have tried the guide http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download

> yum install --enablerepo=updates-testing qgis qgis-python qgis-grass qgis-mapserver

it shows only QGIS 1.8 is available

any guide on installation of QGIS 1.9?

Comment: 1.9 is beta and will be the stable release at 2.0

Comment: thanks, I will use 1.8 then until the next stable release

Comment: Copying answer from [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72206/any-qgis-2-0-updated-rpm-for-fedora/72209#72209) No official package has been released yet and most likely, **no upgrade will be released for the current versions (F18 / F19)** due to the fact, that the upgrade will require upgrading almost all plugins as well (and some of them don't have an update version available yet). Most likely, **F20 will be released with QGIS 2.0**. For the time being, I created an alternative repository. At the moment only x86_64 binaries for Fedora 19 and Fedora 18 are available. On request, I ca