# Any QGIS 2.0 updated RPM for Fedora?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2, fedora

I'm very excited about the new release of QGIS (2.0), and would like to install it on my Fedora 18 machine. I couldn't find any relevant RPMs, and the documentation on the QGIS main site for Fedora is pretty old (16/17).

Did anyone did it and can throw some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I'm not familiar with the term "RPM" - would you be able to edit your question to spell it out once and/or embed a link to where it is defined, please?

Comment: As excited as you are ... i would advise you to be a little patient and wait, till really everything is ready, when compiling from source is no option. It seems like the release annoucement came a bit too early and there are many hick-ups and packaging problems at the moment. @PolyGeo: .RPM is a install package format, like .DEB for Debian, Ubuntu etc.

Comment: RPM = RedHat Package Manager, the backend package management system used by Red Hat Linux (including Fedora and RHEL) and Red Hat distribution forks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No official package has been released yet and most likely, **no upgrade will be released for the current versions (F18 / F19)** due to the fact, that the upgrade will require upgrading almost all plugins as well (and some of them don't have an update version available yet). Most likely, **F20 will be released with QGIS 2.0**.

For the time being, I created an alternative repository. At the moment only x86_64 binaries for Fedora 19 and Fedora 18 are available. On request, I can also add others.

Installation instructions:

```
sudo wget fedora.vitu.ch/QGIS/qgis.repo -P /etc/yum.repos.d/
sudo rpm --import http://fedora.vitu.ch/Fedora/RPM-GPG-Key-vitu
sudo yum update
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assumed they won't publish a package for Fedora 18. I guess i'll upgrade my system soon.

Comment: Installation instructions for alternative repository available, please let me know if there are problems.

Comment: Thanks! i got this error message: Resolving fedora.vitu.ch (fedora.vitu.ch)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘fedora.vitu.ch’

Comment: Thanks! Do you think making a Fedora18 package would be hard?

Comment: fc18.x86_64 rpms added to the repo

Answer (score 2):

You can now compile QGIS 2 easily locally, see

http://blog.neteler.org/compiling-qgis-2-0-1-for-fedora-19-in-a-few-steps/

The approach uses "mock" which compiles all in an encapsulated environment without cluttering the system. May work for F18 as well.